# Reading documents from the Couchbase bucket as batches

Tags: java, couchbase

I have a Couchbase cluster which has around 25M documents. I am able to read them sequentially and also I have a function that can read a specific number of documents from the database. But my use case is slightly different since I cannot store all the 25M documents (each document is huge) in memory.

I need to process the documents in batches, say 1M/batch, push that batch to my memory, (do some operation on those documents) and push the next batch.

The function which I have written to read specific number of documents doesn't ensure that it returns a different set of documents when called again.

Is there a way by which I can complete this functionality? I also have a function which can create documents in batches. I am not sure if I can write a similar function that can read the documents in batches. The function is given below.

```
public void createMultipleCustomerDocuments(String docId, Customer myCust, long numDocs) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonObject content = JsonObject.fromJson(gson.toJson(myCust));
        JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.create(docId, content);
        jsonDocuments.add(document);
        documentCounter++;

        if (documentCounter == numDocs) {
            Observable.from(jsonDocuments).flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                public Observable<JsonDocument > call(final JsonDocument docToInsert) {
                    return (theBucket.async().upsert(docToInsert));
                }
            }).last().toBlocking().single();

            documentCounter = 0;
            //System.out.println("Batch counter: " + batchCounter++);

        }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Your question is about reading documents in batches, and you've posted code for writing documents. Your rx code to upsert looks fine. How about posting what you've tried for loading in batches.

Comment: The problem is I wasn't able to get an idea on how to get the documents from the server. The `just` function needs the keys right? I don't have the access to the keys. So I couldn't write a similar function for reading the documents.

Comment: You don't know the keys? Ignoring the batching, how do you intend to specify the documents you need. Views? N1QL? Would those be suitable? You haven't specified that in the question. I think you probably should update the question to properly explain your problem properly.

Comment: I was not even store the 25M+ keys in the application layer. So I was left with the option of using views by using the `limit` and `skip` functions. At the time of posting this question, I was planning to get the documents using rx code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to create a view which containing all of the documents, and then querying the view with skip and limit. (Can use `.startKey()` and `startKeyId()` functions instead of `skip()` to avoid overhead.)

but, remember not to keep that view in a production env, it will be cpu hog.

Another option, use the DCP protocol to replicate the database into your app. but it is more work.

Comment: Yes. That's the way. I even found an optimized way which won't use `skip` function. You can use `.startKey()` and `.startKeyDocId()` functions which won't be much of an overhead to the processor.

I am not sure about the DCP protocol. How does it work?

Comment: You need to create a small app that hooks into couchbase DCP protocol.
this is the internal couchbase protocol and it doesn't have an overload on the cluster

I do suggest that you start with the view. as it much easier to implement at first. if it doesn't work as desired go to the more complicated solutions.

Comment: The view works fine. I am also able to work with it using multiple threads. Will try out this option if I start encountering new problems! Thanks!